# Assign request response to the global variable - Module Javascript

Tags: javascript

Suppose I create a `BookController` and have a function like the example below in this controller:

```
import Fetch from './Fetch.js';

// GET
async function getAllBooks() {
  const books = await Fetch.get('/books');
}
```

Still in the `BookController.js` file, could I export this function to call it in another js file as below?

```
function getAll() {   
  return getAllBooks();
}

export default {
  getAll,
};
```

Another thing, is it possible to transform the `const books` into a global variable and export that variable so that I can use it anywhere?

**Fetch.js**

```
// Fetch.js
const _apiHost = 'https://api.example';

async function request(url, params, method = 'GET') {

  const options = {
    method,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };

  if (params) {   
    if (method === 'GET') {
      url += '?' + objectToQueryString(params);
    } else {        
      options.body = JSON.stringify(params);      
    }
  }

  const response = await fetch(_apiHost + url, options);

  if (response.status !== 200) {
    return generateErrorResponse('The server responded with an unexpected status.');
  }

  const result = await response.json();

  return result;

}

function objectToQueryString(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(key => key + '=' + obj[key]).join('&'); 
}

function generateErrorResponse(message) {
  return {
    status : 'error',
    message
  };
}

function get(url, params) {   
  return request(url, params);
}

function create(url, params) {    
  return request(url, params, 'POST');
}

 function update(url, params) {
  return request(url, params, 'PUT');
}

function remove(url, params) {   
  return request(url, params, 'DELETE');
}

export default {
  get,
  create,
  update,
  remove
};
```

Comment: If javascript functions work like functions in other languages then books will not exist outside of the scope of the function.  Why not declare books as a global in the module then export that?

Comment: `getAllBooks` does not return anything and it would not make sense for it to be a global. You need to rethink your code if it has to be a global.

Comment: `getAllBooks` returns the data, because in the `Fetch.js` file imported at the beginning of the `BookController` it makes a request in the database.

Comment: `getAllBooks` doesn't have a return statement, so it doesn't return anything.

Comment: I added the `Fetch.js` file to the question, see that there is a return for the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript we can use global variable with the use of window object.

declare book variable like `window.books="some value"` intead of `const books`.

in the same way use function also:

```
window.getAll = () => {   
  return getAllBooks();
}
```

and get value anywhere.